# Error: Getting error related to http equiv while validating

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

This error pops up on my website, while trying the validator tools.

Error: Attribute http-equiv not allowed on element meta at this point.

From line 23, column 1; to line 23, column 69

min.css">↩↩<meta

I'm getting this errors while using this:

https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.thecityceleb.com%2F

Comment: You have a poorly written WordPress  theme, most likely. The validator detected some dodgy HTML in your page.

Comment: What's the solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: While trying to use the validator, I get this html error, How can I fix it. My website is thecityceleb.com

"
This error pops up on my website, while trying the validator tools.

Error: Attribute http-equiv not allowed on element meta at this point.

From line 23, column 1; to line 23, column 69

min.css">↩↩<meta"